# How to add a value of a variable to the NAME of a variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I am making a function where it takes in $name and $query as parameters to auto generate the 3 variables I need for a MySQL query.

Here is the code:

```
function makeQuery($name, $query){

}
```

And the variables:

```
$checkTeach = "SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE user_id LIKE '%2309%'";
$CTquery = mysqli_query($dbconn, $checkWho);
$CTrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($CWquery);
```

Before I go onto my question I want to keep checkTeach in the name parameter and where it says CT it should be replaced with checkTeach.

So in a way I want it to look like this:

```
function makeQuery($name, $query){
    $valueof($name)variable = $query;
    $(valueof$name variable)query = mysqli_query($dbconn, $valueof($name)variable);
    $(valueof$name variable)row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($(valueof$name variable)query);
}
```

One last question:
Should I manually declare these 3 variables above or should I use a function? Right now I have tons of those sets of 3 variables and I feel it would be easier with a function

Comment: Do you need this to stay in the function or will it be global?

Comment: If you need a more dynamic structure, why not create a data structure that can hold it? A single associative array can do this. Saying "I have tons of those sets of 3 variables" is a hint that you need some kind of data structure to pass around instead.

Comment: So do you recommend making an array with it? and if so is it possible to make it with a function or add in data with a function. But I COMPLETELY doubt you can do it

Answer (score 1):

Look into using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). However, in your example, you need to consider if variable variables are the correct solution over an array, for example.